# Inline-Block For Center Aligned Navigation Not Displaying Horizontal in IE 11+

Tags: html, css

So, I'm trying to create a centered horizontal menu in a fixed-width parent container. I set both the ul and li elements to display as inline-block and the parent to text-align and center. This method works in FF and Chrome, but in IE, the list is centered, but displaying vertically. This is with IE 11.

Here's the breakdown:

```
.menu {
width: 700px;
height: 35px;
background-color: #767676;
text-align:center;
}

.menu ul {
    list-style:none; 
    display:inline-block; 
    padding:0px; 
    margin:0px;   }

.menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #B9E9A8;
    width: 120px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#4F4F4F;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:35px;
      }


.menu li a {
    color:#3A3A3A;
    text-decoration:none; 
    display:block;
     }

.menu li a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#507B28;
      }
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
.menu {
width: 700px;
height: 35px;
background-color: #767676;
text-align:center;
}

.menu ul {
    list-style:none; 
    display:block; 
    text-align: center;
    padding:0px; 
    margin:0px;   }

.menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #B9E9A8;
    width: 120px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#4F4F4F;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:35px;
      }


.menu li a {
    color:#3A3A3A;
    text-decoration:none; 
    display:block;
     }

.menu li a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#507B28;
      }
```

All I have done is to keep the ul a block element. By making it inline-block, it is only going to have the width of its contents which are all inline elements too, meaning it will just fill up from the left. By making it a block, it will fill in the whole line, and text-align center will then center the inline-block contents.

Comment: Thanks, but it appears as though it's still displaying the horizontal menu as vertical in IE.

Comment: New to all of this, but why was my question voted down?